# Blocked from posting question as site thinks it is a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I recently asked (and answered) the question:

[Q: Write with Nifi to Kudu in Cloudera Data Platform CDP public cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962878/write-with-nifi-to-kudu-in-cloudera-data-platform-cdp-public-cloud)

I am now trying to ask the opposite, how to read rather than write. Though the question is similar and I don't know the answer yet, I already know the answer will turn out to be quite different.

Assuming it is not a problem that the questions are similar (but opposite), is there a straightforward way to 'post anyway because it is not a duplicate' or is a more creative solution needed?

[image]

Comment: When do you get the duplicate warning?  After typing the title?  Or is looking at the question body too?

Comment: Considering people are able to post questions with exactly the same titles save one character, with the exact same body, I find it difficult to believe the system is preventing you from posting a question due to duplication...

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to give a screenshot or something. I've not seen or heard of a duplicate block

Comment: It gave the message when trying to post the question (not even at the review). I tried to completely change the title, that had no effect. Then I tried my original (similar) title with a completely different body. That worked. Afterwards I edited in the right (similar) body, it is now here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015000/q-read-from-kudu-with-nifi-in-cloudera-data-platform-cdp-public-cloud

Comment: @Machavity Added a screenshot

Comment: @HereticMonkey Added a screenshot. Note that clicking again on 'post your question' does not help.

Comment: the features of this site never cease to amaze me... maybe the system wrongly detected that you're trying to ask the same question again (happens a lot)...

Comment: Weird, never seen that before. I do see that the question the error points to, "Read from Kudu with Nifi in Cloudera Data Platform CDP public cloud" is different from the one mentioned in your meta question: "Write with Nifi to Kudu in Cloudera Data Platform CDP public cloud", so it's not saying your new question is a dupe of the Write question, but rather a dupe of some other Read question. Might want to check to make sure you don't have two questions out there...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I do have 2 questions now as intended (just pretended to make a third one to reproduce the error for the screenshot). But also got the error referring to the first one while I was trying to create the second one.

Comment: It appears as though you've purposefully created duplicates. I would close your [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63015000/215552) and [Write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62962878/215552) questions as duplicates of your [Read/Write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62956604/215552) question...

Comment: @HereticMonkey The Read/Write question is about Kafka. The individual Read and Write questions are about Kudu (a completely different thing)

Comment: They are certainly different things! But spelled so tantalizingly similarly :). I'd probably just combine the Read and Write Kudu questions into one question like the Kafka question. Maybe restructure the titles and bodies so they differ more; that's probably what's tripping up the auto-detector (and my brain-detector :)).

Answer (score -2):

As you have asked (and answered) a question with the title [Write with Nifi to Kudu in Cloudera Data Platform CDP public cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962878/write-with-nifi-to-kudu-in-cloudera-data-platform-cdp-public-cloud) before and now asking the opposite question as how to read, presumably they differs by only one word i.e. ***read*** against ***write***.

Though I haven't faced exactly the same situation in the course of asking questions, but have often faced the same while editing questions correcting the question headings.

My wild guess is, there is a script involved, which compares the new question heading with the existing ones and unless certain percentage of texts are indifferent, the system would would block you from raising the question with the error you have depicted.

A simple solution is, ensuring the question is not a duplicate, frame the question with a different verbatim.